# What adhesive should I use to repair a glass and silicone cake mould

Tags: equipment, silicone

I have a silicon and glass cake mould with the round base made of glass with some silicone feet and a detachable rim made of silicone. One of the feet came lose and dropped off.

What glue I can use to re-attach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A high heat silicone adhesive will do the trick. Something like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/ProSeal-3-oz-Clear-RTV-Silicone-Adhesive-and-Sealant-12-Pack-80066/202805532) (obviously only need to buy one, not a whole case).

Also, I've had some luck with oven door adhesive (though never tried on cookware) and [auto adhesive](https://www.jbweld.com/products/j-b-weld-twin-tube).

All are oven safe up to 400-500F continuous, so you should be good for baking.